# Отмена действия при нажатии на стрелочки в input'е

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Появилась необходимость убрать перемещение курсора в начало/конец input'а при нажатии стрелочек вверх/вниз. Как это реализовать? Желательно с использованием jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) для события `keydown`

```js
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
  if (["ArrowDown", "ArrowUp"].indexOf(e.key) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Some value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот, я бы сделал так, instead ответ frozencoast'a

```js
$('input').keydown((e)=>{
    if(e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Some value">
```

Или можно еще проще:

```js
$('input').keydown((e)=>(e.keyCode === 38 || e.keyCode === 40) ? e.preventDefault() : 0);
```